# Laravel Target Spatie Class is not instantiable while building

Tags: dependency-injection, laravel-8

In Laravel 8.0 with Spatie\MediaLibray v10 I try to save images as responsive for images received from my Api.  But I get the following error: `Target Spatie\MediaLibrary\ResponsiveImages\WidthCalculator\WidthCalculator] is not instantiable while building [Spatie\MediaLibrary\ResponsiveImages\ResponsiveImageGenerator]`.  
I cannot understand why the error only occurs on the production server, since both is setup with Php version 8.1 and has the necessary libraries installed.  What is also strange is that the images is still  saved, they just do not have all the responsive extras in the image directory.  
So to save coded lines I created a single `SaveImagesClass` that takes as constructor an instance of a `ModelEventClass` that contains the model save logic in the form of anonymous function injected from the controller.  The relevance of this is, I have over 11 different sections that saves differing data to different models with or without images and a shorter coded path was needed to save the data.
The save classes are registered in the `AppServiceProvider` file:

```
        $this->app->bind(SaveImagesInterface::class, SaveImagesClass::class);
        $this->app->bind(SaveImagesClass::class, function ($app) {
            return new SaveImagesClass($app->make(ModelEventClass::class));
        });
```

```
class SaveImagesClass implements SaveImagesInterface {

    use ResponseJsonTrait;

    public function __construct(
        protected ModelEventClass $modelEventClass
    )
    {}

    public function store(Request $request, array $data): array 
    {
        try {            
            $ids = [];
            $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                if(!$this->modelEventClass->exists($value, $user_id)) {

                    $this->modelEventClass->insert($request, $value["data"], $chunk["image"]);
                    $ids[] = $value["data"]["id"];
                }
            }
            $msg = __("Saved");
            
            return $this->resultArray($msg, 200, $ids);
        } catch(\Exception $e) {
            $msg = $e->getMessage(); // __("Error occurred while trying to execute command.");
            return $this->resultArray($msg, 500, null, false);
        }
    }
}
```

```
class ModelEventClass {

    public function __construct(
        protected Closure $insert_model_data,
        protected Closure $model_data_exists
        )
    {}

    public function insert(Request $request, array $data, ?string $image_name): void
    {
        $local = Closure::fromCallable($this->insert_model_data);
        $local($request, $data, $image_name);
    }

    public function exists(array $value, int $user_id): bool
    {
        $local = Closure::fromCallable($this->model_data_exists);
        return $local($value, $user_id);
    }
}
```

In controller:

```
/**
     * Create a new constructor for this controller
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->saveImagesClass = new SaveImagesClass(new ModelEventClass(function(Request $request, array $data, ?string $image_name): void {
            $create = Model::create($data);
            
            if(isset($image_name)) {
                $uuid = (string) Str::uuid();
                $create->addMediaFromRequest($image_name)
                ->setName($uuid)
                ->withResponsiveImages()  // this causes the error when data is saved
                ->toMediaCollection();
            }
        }, function(array $value, int $user_id): bool {
            return Model::where("user_id", "=", $user_id)
            ->where("qr_id", "=", $value["qr_id"])
            ->where("date", "=", $value["date"])
            ->exists();
        }));
    }
```

---

**Edit 1**
I removed all depencies and saved images directly in the controller. The error persists.

---

**Edit 2**
I read from [here](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/blob/main/src/MediaLibraryServiceProvider.php) that there is a `MediaLibraryServiceProvider` that shows the services that should be registered.  Don't know why they are not registered out of the box, but I copied the line

```
$this->app->bind(WidthCalculator::class, config('media-library.responsive_images.width_calculator'));
```

into my `AppServiceProvider` register method.  This removed the error but lead to a new error:

```
Target [Spatie\MediaLibrary\ResponsiveImages\TinyPlaceholderGenerator\TinyPlaceholderGenerator] is not instantiable while building [Spatie\MediaLibrary\ResponsiveImages\ResponsiveImageGenerator]
```

So I also copied the relevant bind method which now gives the responsive images, but lead to a new error:

```
No hint path defined for [media-library]
```

I tried resolving that error by adding `$this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../resources/views', 'media-library');` to the boot method.  But yet another error `View [placeholderSvg] not found` showed its head.

Does anybody know why this error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was in my last edit: just add the composer package service provider class to the `app.config` providers block.

```
Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaLibraryServiceProvider::class,
```

I do feel the fool. To many Api's make you look for problems that does not fit the working Api's ethos.